# calculating the probability of poker hands (three of a kind, full house)

Tags: probability

Are these the correct formulas for each of the following? If not, please explain!

Find the probability of obtaining three of a kind in a 5-card hand as a fraction.

$$\frac{C(4,1) \times C(9,1)}{C(52,3)}$$

Find the probability of obtaining a full house(three of a kind together with a pair) in a 5-card hand as a fraction.

$$\frac{C(4,3) \times C(4,2)}{C(13,1) \times C(12,1)}$$

Comment: What do you mean "the given $5$-card poker hand"?  Are you just asking for the probability of getting three of a kind?

Comment: These formulas are very hard to understand.  Why is the denominator in the first one $\binom {52}3$?  Aren't you drawing $5$ cards?  (the numerator makes even less sense).

Comment: @lulu  yes, this is why I am not sure how to get the answers to them. These formulas are ways that I thought I could get the answer to, but I can't seem to get it

Comment: The hand "AAAAK" shouldn't be counted as 3 of a kind right?

Comment: Well...just do it in stages.  How many ways to get a three of a kind are there?  You need to choose a rank for the triple, $\binom {13}1$ choices.  You need to choose three of that rank, $\binom 43$. You need to pick two  other ranks, $\binom {12}2$, and you need one card from each $\left( \binom 41 \right)^2$ So just multiply those, and divide by $\binom {52}5$.

Comment: @Coolwater  That is my understanding.  And neither should $AAAKK$.

Answer (score 4):

For three of a kind, the hand will look like $\{x,x,x,y,z\}$ for some distinct values $x,y,z \in \{A,2,3,\ldots,K\}$. (We'll just look at the numerical values to start, and look at suits later). There are ${13\choose1}$ ways to choose $x$. There are $12$ remaining values available to $y$ and $z$, so there are ${12\choose2}$ ways to choose these singletons.

Now look at the suits. There are $4\choose3$ ways to choose the three suits for $x$, and $4\choose1$ ways for each of $y$ and $z$.

Finally, there are $52\choose5$ possible five-card hands. So, the probability of three of a kind is:

$$\frac{{13\choose1}{12\choose2}{4\choose3}{4\choose1}{4\choose1}}{52\choose5}$$